# Find and replace numbers using do while loop

Tags: vb.net, do-while

I am using find and replace to remove white space in time values.

For example "50 " should read as "50"

```
Dim index As Integer = 0
    Do
        Dim fileReader As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(TextBox1.Text).Replace(index & " ", index)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(TextBox1.Text, fileReader, False)
        index += 1
    Loop Until index = 50
```

The only problem is that the loop until doesn't work as a value of say 55 will be replace also I'm guessing this is because the number is not being read as a whole so "55 " is read as "5 "

I would also like to read the system path and not use a textbox to manually input the file name

Comment: We need to see a small sample of the input data and required output to be able to help.

Comment: Don't read the file every time! Load it once to a string variable and modify that variable. When you are done, you write the string back to the file.

Comment: _"I would also like to read the system path and not use a textbox"_ What _system path_?